# Знаки препинания при деепричастиях

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

> Я боюсь, получив — потерять, только встретившись — сразу расстаться.

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Я боюсь, получив, (–) потерять, только встретившись, (–) сразу расстаться.**

Обособление = запятые с обеих сторон, даже перед тире. Сами же тире могут использоваться, чтобы подчеркнуть параллелизм.

Comment: В подтверждение сказанного: *Я весь дрожал, и мне хотелось, Об стенку лоб разбив, ― упасть… [Сергей Довлатов. Наши (1983)]*